# конвертор из std::string в QString

Tags: c++, qt

есть функция, возвращающая string а её результат нужно внести в QListWidget который принимает на вход QSringList. на обычный оператор = между string  и QString компилятор ругается

Answer (score 4):

Для преобразования из `std::string` в `QString`, в Qt есть статическая функция [QString::fromStdString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString). И еще есть парная ей функция `QString::fromStdWString()`.

Comment: стоит оговориться, что `QString::fromStdString()` ожидает `std::string` в utf-8. Если кодировка другая (включая Latin-1), то лучше воспользоваться различными вариантами конвертации из `char *`.